# "Kommst du mit ins Kino?": Warum ist "mit" nicht am Ende des Satzes?

Tags: usage, sentence-structure

Mich würde es interessieren, warum bei *mitgehen*, *mitkommen* usw. die Partikel *mit* im Satz nicht am Ende kommt?
Beispiel:

> Kommst du mit ins Kino?

Comment: Besides, "Kommst du ins Kino mit?" is also correct.

Answer (score 5):

"[I]ns Kino" ist eine nachgestellte Orts-/Zielbezeichnung. Der eigentliche (Kern-)Satz lautet: "Kommst du mit?".

Prinzipiell kannst du dir aussuchen, ob du Zusatzinformationen in den **Verb + ... + *mit*** Rahmen einbaust oder außen herum platzierst. Beide Formen sind korrekt. Im schlimmsten Fall ist das Ergebnis etwas unüblich oder schwierig zu verstehen.